# Can I enable external access for 1 site collection in CSOM?

Tags: external-users

O365, I have some existing site collections. I am building some custom logic. I would like to enable external access for some site collections in CSOM. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below two references:

```
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement;
```

After that try the below code:

```
using (var tenantContext = new ClientContext("https://yourtenantName-admin.sharepoint.com"))
{
    // Get properties of new Site Collection
    SiteProperties siteprops = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl("https://sitecollectionurl.sharepoint.com/", true);
    tenantContext.Load(siteprops);
    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();

    // Set the Sharing option of the new site collection
    siteprops.SharingCapability = SharingCapabilities.ExternalUserSharingOnly;
    siteprops.Update();
    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

You can set the sharing values as below:

1) Disabled

2) ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly

3) ExternalUserAndGuestSharing

4) ExternalUserSharingOnly

Reference - [SETTING SITE COLLECTION SHARING BY CODE](https://amtopmblog.azurewebsites.net/2014/07/17/setting-site-collection-sharing-by-code/)

Comment: Thank you, which permissions do I need to run this code?

Comment: Sharepoint admin permissions would be required as we are using the tenant context

Comment: this sample is missing one line of code, tenant is undefined without this: var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);